# PhpStorm doesn't stop on conditional breakpoints in PHP Code

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, conditional-breakpoint

I'm using PhpStorm 2016.3.2 and my problem is it doesn't stop on conditional breakpoints. Normal breakpoints work fine.

Condition I have: `$id == 5`

Also, if I activate the Checkbox "Log message to console" nothing happens, I don't see any new messages in terminal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with PhpStorm 9 one day.

I solved it by using the `xdebug_break` function directly. Which in no case is as comfortable as the build in solution. On the next PhpStorm Update it worked for me with no change on my side.

```
if($id == 5){
    xdebug_break();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I was expecting wrong value in my condition, which never occurs :-)